# Running Macro Once Does Not Do Anything. Running the Macro Again Works

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having some trouble with a macro I've been working on. It's used to delete blanks (over a million blank rows) when another separate macro is run. If I get this one working, I would like to merge the two macros together.

Here is the macro:

```
Sub Test()
DeleteBlankTableRows ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
End Sub
Sub DeleteBlankTableRows(ByVal tbl As ListObject)
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = tbl.DataBodyRange ' Get table data rows range.
Dim DirArray As Variant
DirArray = rng.Value2       ' Save table values to array.

' LOOP THROUGH ARRAY OF TABLE VALUES
Dim rowTMP As Long
Dim colTMP As Long
Dim combinedTMP As String
Dim rangeToDelete As Range

'  Loop through rows.
For rowTMP = LBound(DirArray) To UBound(DirArray)
    combinedTMP = vbNullString  ' Clear temp variable.

    ' Loop through each cell in the row and get all values combined.
    For colTMP = 1 To tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count
        combinedTMP = combinedTMP & DirArray(rowTMP, colTMP)
    Next colTMP

    ' Check if row is blank.
    If combinedTMP = vbNullString Then
        ' Row is blank.  Add this blank row to the range-to-delete.
        If rangeToDelete Is Nothing Then
            Set rangeToDelete = tbl.ListRows(rowTMP).Range
        Else
            Set rangeToDelete = Union(rangeToDelete, tbl.ListRows(rowTMP).Range)
        End If
    End If
Next rowTMP

' DELETE BLANK TABLE ROWS (if any)
If Not rangeToDelete Is Nothing Then rangeToDelete.Delete
End Sub
```

First time it is run, it loads and acts like it's going to work. Less than a minute after loading...nothing happens (at least, visually). I run it again and it loads quickly; this time, the blank rows are visually gone.

Comment: variable tbl is not defined, what does it refer to

Comment: Don't use Activesheet. Use a specific parent sheet name reference.

Answer (score 0):

A similar idea using an explicit parent sheet reference and Index and Max to determine if a row is blank.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DeleteRowsIfBlank()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, table As ListObject, arr(), i As Long, counter As Long, unionRng As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set table = ws.ListObjects(1)
    arr = table.DataBodyRange.Value
    counter = table.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Row
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If Application.Max(Application.Index(arr, i, 0)) = 0 Then
            If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, table.Range.Rows(counter))
            Else
                Set unionRng = table.Range.Rows(counter)
            End If
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    Next
    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the more streamlined code, QHarr. It works, but after I run it twice. It still takes about 30 seconds the first time and then 1 second the next time (which then removes the blanks). Do you think maybe the first macro is still running in the background? Is that why I have to run this macro twice?

Comment: I am not sure what other code you have running. If you run only the above code it doesn't call anything else unless you have some event based code elsewhere. It should delete on first run.